# How to access ALL documents in a CouchDB database?

Tags: curl, couchdb

How do I iterate over all CouchDB documents? As I know CouchDB can be accessed through `curl` but I'm unable to get to any documents because I can't figure out the syntax for URLs.

I've a database `ibmuwarticles` and I found the `curl` syntax for verifying that it exists through the `_all_dbs` parameter:

```
curl -X GET http://10.10.211.133:5984/_all_dbs 
["ibmuwarticles"]
```

But how do I actually access data in it? What would be the `curl` syntax and parameter after a slash to access data in `ibmuwarticles`?

I tried guessing and used `_all_data` slash parameter, but it didn't work

```
curl -X GET http://10.10.211.133:5984/_all_data
{"error":"illegal_database_name","reason":"Only lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter."}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the syntax is `/db_name/_all_docs`. See the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html) for further details.

So in your case it would be the following:

```
curl -X GET http://10.10.211.133:5984/ibmuwarticles/_all_docs
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It worked. Ur a computer wizard genius.  :) Accepting your answer. U saved my day.

Comment: No worries. The CouchDB documentation is very good - you may want to bookmark it for future reference if you're working with it a lot

Comment: One more question - All of the data is like this: `{"id":"student-guide-a","key":"sudent-guide-a","value":{"rev":"1-3afd3f0bf9259806287602140dc6effa"}}` It only contains `rev` id (not sure what that is? revision id?). Do you know how to access the full data for each id? I'm guessing I will need to use `rev` to do a follow-up query. Do you know about this by any chance? I'll try to find about it in documentation but thought I'd ask you first.

Comment: That's easy - just set the include_docs parameter to true eg `curl -X GET http://10.10.211.133:5984/ibmuwarticles/_all_docs?include_docs=true` . `rev` is, as you say, the revision ID. There's a full list of all the available parameters on the page I linked to - that should help in getting the data in the format you need

Comment: @FlynSequeira Don't post new questions as comments. If you can't find the answer already and you need help create a new question.

Comment: Note that this will include design documents as well (2.1.0).

Comment: This will return `_design/index` & `_design/views` if you have created.